# I want to generate a PSK for VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, wpa2-psk

I want to generate a PSK file for connecting the VPN in linux

I have 3 certificates and network servers and peer address

1. intermediateCA.cer
2. ProdBroker.cer
3. TestBroker.cer

I am not able to get the way out for generating PSK file

Comment: There is no such thing as a PSK file. PSK = Pre-shared key is mostly a WiFi thing. In some VPN software there is something similar: A “shared secret”. I guess you’re trying to follow some sort of guide. Please tell us which one.

Comment: I want to access the one API of money transfer ( Safaricom B2C) we need to hit their servers. But without connecting VPN i am not able to access their URLs thats why i need to connect VPN  they ask to configure the vpn and send them PSK to him..But i am not sure how can i get this psk file..

They have given on doc in which pre shared key is showing to be shared later , I am bit confuse who is giving shared key..

Comment: I am following  : https://blog.muya.co.ke/safaricom-mpesa-b2c-api-developer-guide/

Please check @DanielB

Answer (score 0):

With an SSL VPN, the [TLS Crypt](https://and%20placed%20within%20the%20client%20config) PSK is a three-part configuration:

1. **TLS Crypt PSK is generated on the server:**

   ```sh
   # Generate TLS Crypt key:
     openvpn --genkey --secret "/etc/openvpn/tls-crypt.key"

   # Ensure correct permissions:
     chmod 600; chown root:root
   ```
2. **[Server Config:](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/)**

   ```sh
   tls_crypt    '/etc/openvpn/tls-crypt.key'
   ```
3. **Client Config:**

   ```xml
   <tls-crypt-v2>
   key contents
   </tls-crypt-v2>
   ```

   - `tls-crypt.key` is disseminated to clients and placed inline within the client config; per client with TLS Crypt v2 or all clients with TLS Crypt